# How to implement two spinners in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the code available at the following link
http://android-helper4u.blogspot.in/2013/03/d-databse-and-spinner-tutorial.html

How to write setonItemSelectedListener for the two spinners.i want to fetch the selected data of the spinners from the database.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: same way as for one spinner.

Comment: Actually code is long ..That's why i have't posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.
declare the strings as shown below

```
    private String[] colors1 = {"  Black","  Brown","  Red","  Orange","  Yellow","  Green","  Blue","  Violet","  Grey","  White"};
    private String[] colors2={"  Black","  Brown","  Red","  Orange","  Yellow","  Green","  Blue","  Violet","  Gold","  Silver"};
    String selstate1,selstate2;
```

and in oncreate(), put this code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors1);
adapter_state1
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_state1);
spinner1.setSelection(0);
selstate1 = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors1);
 adapter_state2
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state2);
spinner2.setSelection(0);
selstate2 = (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem();

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and let your activity implement OnItemSelectedListener and using switch case

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (position) {
    case R.id.spinner1:
        spinner1.setSelection(position);
         selstate1 = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        spinner2.setSelection(position);
         selstate2 = (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
        break;
```

the selected item of the spinners are stored in selstate1 and selstate2 strings respectively

Comment: assign the data from your database to strings and just implement as shown above

Comment: what should i write for the rundatabase() method for the two spinners.